# JQuery UI Sortable: how to make items have droppable behavior (ex. hoverClass)?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I am using JQuery UI's drag and drop for a web application.

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="list">
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

and Javscript:

```
$('#list').sortable({containment: 'parent'});
```

When I drag, move, and drop an item, all items are aligned nicely verticially, which I like it.

Now I hope that when I drag and hover an item over another item, the item below can show some visual effects similar to the hoverClass available in JQuery UI's Droppable.

How can I do it?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: i dont think thats possible in sortable. The nearest you can get is the placeholder property which indicates where the item can be dropped

Answer (score 1):

For the `hoverClass` you can do something simiar with the `over` and `out` methods. The `start` and `stop` could also help you.

```js
 $('.sortable').sortable({ 
    over : function(){
         $(this).addClass('valid');
     },
     out : function(){
          $(this).removeClass('valid');
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your input. I tried it. $(this).addClass('valid') affects a whole sort list, not the question being dropped over. Regards.

Comment: With the `receive` method you can access the element being dropped.

Comment: receive event seems not get called when one object hovers over and is dropped over an object in the SAME sortable list.

Answer (score 1):

As stated before, `$(this)` points to the current sortable you are hovering on a `over` typed event.
The most reliable way of implementing sortable hovering with jQuery is as follow:

```
$('#some-element').sortable({
    start: {
        ui.item.parent().addClass('sortable-hover');
    },
    over: {
        $('.sortable-hover').removeClass('sortable-hover');
        $(this).addClass('sortable-hover');
    },
    stop: {
        ui.item.parent().removeClass('sortable-hover');
    }
});
```

You can add more logic as required.

Hope it helps,
-- José

Answer (score 1):

I hope that's what you are looking for

```
$('#list').sortable({
    containment: 'parent',
    start: function() {
        $(this).addClass('sortable-hover');
    },
    over: function() {
        $('#list').removeClass('sortable-hover');
        $(this).addClass('sortable-hover');
    },
    stop: function) {
        $('#list').removeClass('sortable-hover');
    },
});
```